# Rails 6 index resource with association stats N+1?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the controller, when calling Review.all, i also need to get statistics on the association :ranks.
It looks like this:

```rb
class Review
  has_many :ranks, as: :rankable, dependent: :destroy
  
  def rank
    ranks.average(:score).to_f || 0
  end
  
  def ranks_count
    ranks.count
  end
end

class Rank < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rankable, polymorphic: true
end

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all.page(params[:page])
  end
end


# index.htlm.slim:
  - @reviews.each do |review|
    li= link_to review
      span
        => review.title
        => review.rank
        => review.ranks_count
```

As a result, for each object in the @reviews collection, i get two SQL sub-queries for the ranks: SELECT AVG and SELECT COUNT.
How can I solve this?

1. I see creating an additional polymorphic Stat model, where i will store AVG and COUNT.
2. There is Review.includes(:ranks) but i don't understand how to use it correctly here.
3. I can additionally query with grouping based on @reviews
   Something like:

```rb
@ranks = Rank.select(:score, :rankable_id).where(rankable: @reviews, rankable_id: @reviews.ids).group_by(&:rankable_id)
```

And then use it further in the view.

What is the best way to solve this, and is it possible to solve it nicely through includes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a left join and select aggregates from the joined tables:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :ranks, as: :rankable, dependent: :destroy

  def self.with_stats
    ranks = Rank.arel_table
    left_joins(:ranks)
      .group(:id)
      .select(
        arel_table[Arel.star], # everything from the reviews table
        ranks[:id].count.as("rank_count") 
        ranks[:score].average.as("rank")
      )
  end
end
```

If you're using Postgres you can use `ranks[Arel.star].count` which is slightly faster then `COUNT("ranks"."id")`.

You can also use a [counter cache](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html) as a read optimization if you use the Rank count a lot.

Comment: This is really interesting and works, I haven't used Arel before.
Only `average` instead of `avg`.  
In the controller it will be like this:  
`@reviews = Review.with_stats.page(params[:page])`
Counter cache in the study process.

Comment: @ChildrenofkoRn yeah, you're right it should be `average` and not `avg`. Edited.

Comment: What if I want to add to this query the conclusion of the author of the review, the existing association:
`belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'`
I know i can load authors like this:
`@reviews = Review.with_stats.includes(:author).page(params[:page])`

Comment: And by querying `with_stats` I got it like this:
`def self.with_stats
      ranks = Rank.arel_table
      users = User.arel_table
      left_joins(:ranks, :author)
        .group(:id, 'users.username')
        .select(
          arel_table[Arel.star],
          ranks[:id].count.as("ranks_size"),
          ranks[:score].average.as("rank_avg"),
          users[:username].as("username")
        )
    end`
I'm not sure that's right.

Comment: Can you please ask this as a separate question? Its very hard to do follow up questions via the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i figured it out on my own)

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the additional queries is not making the average and count instance methods - because that'll require to load everything once again, but make your query return the average and count at once;

```
Review
  .joins(:ranks)
  .select('avg(score)::float, count(ranks.id)')
  .group(:id)
```

With something like this;

```
-- select * from reviews;

 id | title |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 1st   | 2023-03-28 06:48:12.375043 | 2023-03-28 06:48:12.375043
  2 | 2nd   | 2023-03-28 06:48:14.333537 | 2023-03-28 06:48:14.333537
(2 rows)

-- select * from ranks;
 id | review_id | score |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-----------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |         1 |     1 | 2023-03-28 06:48:26.513838 | 2023-03-28 06:48:26.513838
  2 |         1 |     2 | 2023-03-28 06:48:28.565594 | 2023-03-28 06:48:28.565594
  3 |         1 |     2 | 2023-03-28 06:50:25.135863 | 2023-03-28 06:50:25.135863
  4 |         2 |     5 | 2023-03-28 06:52:46.001207 | 2023-03-28 06:52:46.001207
(4 rows)
```

You'll get this;

```
Review.joins(:ranks).select('avg(score)::float, count(ranks.id)').group(:id).as_json

SELECT avg(score)::float, count(ranks.id) FROM "reviews" INNER JOIN "ranks" ON "ranks"."review_id" = "reviews"."id" GROUP BY "reviews"."id"

# => [{"avg"=>5.0, "count"=>1, "id"=>nil}, {"avg"=>1.6666666666666667, "count"=>3, "id"=>nil}]
```

(`as_json` isn't really necessary, it's just a way to show it)

Comment: Select isn't accumulative so you'll have to select reviews.* as well to get a useful result. You also need `avg(ranks.score)::float`